# DXF to GeoJSON conversion gets coordinates completely wrong?

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, dxf

I am using GDAL and the ogr2ogr tool in order to convert a file from a DXF to GeoJSON but at the same time convert the coordinates to another CRS, from Sweref 99TM to WGS84.

The issue I am facing is that the coordinates gets very wacky when the projection is being changed.

I am using this command:
`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:3006 -t_srs EPSG:4326 test1.geojson test1.dxf`

All the coordinates is something like:
`geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 62.30984294549225, 3.52484086442923, 0.0 ] }` when in reality the 3 should be 16-something and the first one isn't correct either.

What could be wrong here? I get that it isn't much to go on, but the files are pretty big and I've manually gone through some of the conversion of coordinates if I skip the projection change and that looks as expected.

Is there something wrong with the DXF or my command, or is there something wrong in the actual projection change?

Comment: Please add the beginning of the output including one complete feature of `ogrinfo -al test1.dxf`

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts come to mind. First, are you confident your source data is in EPSG:3006? Second, you said you tried skipping the projection change; do you mean you converted to .geojson and left the output coordinate system untouched? i.e. your resulting .geojson was EPSG:3006? If so, what happens if you then project your resulting .geojson from EPSG:3006 to EPSG:4326? Although adding a step, that may help you diagnose where the problem is occurring. i.e. if you still get wrong coordinates, I would suspect the coordinate system in the .dxf is misspecified or perhaps there's an AutoCAD block in the file or a similar artifact.